# is it possible to use different ImageDataGenerator for different classes?

Tags: imagedatagenerator

`for exemple
ImageDataGenerator for train/cats;
and
ImageDataGenerator for train/dogs.

Probleme :
Create the train_image_generator

## Create the train_image_generator

`train_image_generator =  image_generator.flow_from_directory( train_path, target_size=(img_shape[0],img_shape[1]), color_mode='rgb', batch_size=4, class_mode='binary')`

## Create the validation_image_generator

`val_image_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(    test_path, target_size=(img_shape[0],img_shape[1]), color_mode='rgb', batch_size=4, class_mode='binary', shuffle=False)` 
is it possible to use different "batch_size" for cats an dogs.